# How can I convert validation error field names to input names in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

I have a CakePHP (latest version) web app with forms and validation all working properly using traditional postback, but now I'm switching some of the forms to submit via ajax. When there are validation errors, I would like to get them back on the client as JSON formatted like so:

```
{
"success":false,
"errors":{
    "data[User][username]":["This is not a valid e-mail address"],
    "data[User][password]":["You must choose a password"]
}}
```

**The keys for the errors array need to correspond to the name attribute on the form fields.** We have some prebuilt client script that is expecting JSON formatted in this way. The good news is that this is very close to what the validationErrors object looks like in CakePHP. So I'm currently doing this in my controller:

```
if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {

} else {
    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
        $this->autoRender = $this->layout = false;
        $response['success'] = false;
        $response['errors'] = $this->User->validationErrors;
        echo json_encode($response);
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

However, this is what the JSON response looks like:

```
{
"success":false,
"errors":{
    "username":["This is not a valid e-mail address"],
    "password":["You must choose a password"]
}}
```

Note that **the errors keys have just the basic database table field names in them.** They are not converted into data[User][username] format, which the FormHelper usually takes care of.

Is there some easy way to adjust the array before I return it? I don't want to simply loop through and prepend "data[User]" because that is not robust enough. I'd like some code I can put in one place and call from various controllers for various models. What does FormHelper use to come up with the input name attributes? Can I tap into that? Should I somehow use a JSON view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because that's the way the `$validationErrors` array is formatted. To obtain the output you want you will have to loop through, there's no way around it.

```
foreach ($this->User->validationErrors as $field => $error) {
  $this->User->validationErrors["data[User][$field]"] = $error;
  unset($this->User->validationErrors[$field]);
}
```

I would suggest instead passing all errors to `json_encode()`. `$this->validationErrors` is a combined list of all model validation errors for that request available on the view (compiled after render). You should move your display logic (echoing json) into your view, and loop through it there.

**in the view**

```
$errors = array();
foreach ($this->validationErrors as $model => $modelErrors) {
  foreach ($modelErrors as $field => $error) {
    $errors["data[$model][$field]"] = $error;
  }
}
$response['errors'] = $errors;
echo json_encode($response);
```

This would output something like this:

```
{
  "success":false,
  "errors": [
      "data[User][username]": "This is not a valid e-mail address",
      "data[User][password]": "This is not a valid password",
      "data[Profile][name]": "Please fill in the field"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The looping works but is there a way that this could be done generically, for all models, rather than hard coding "User"? I'd like to put it in AppController.php so that any model could pass validationErrors to it and get the reformatted array. You mention looping on `$this->validationErrors` but I don't think such an object exists. It's null for me even when `$this->User->validationErrors` is not null.

Comment: `$this->validationErrors` is only available on the view, so you'll have to do it from there. You shouldn't be echoing json directly from the controller anyway, it's bad practice. I updated the answer with how to loop through the errors and output how you want. You may consider putting the code in a helper to stay DRY.

Comment: I was able to take your suggested view code and put it in a shared view. Now when I want to return validation errors as JSON from any controller based on any model or combination of models, I just validate (or attempt to save) in the controller and then do `$this->layout = 'ajax'; $this->viewPath = 'shared'; $this->view = 'json_validation';` and then exit. This answers my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
I have created a small recursive function to create validation error as a string with column name so that can be passed as json object.

 /**
     * prepare erorr message to be displayed from js
     *
     * @param array   $errors  validation error array
     * @param stringn $message refernce variable
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function parseValidationErrors($errors, &$message)
    {
        foreach ($errors as $columnName => $error) {
            $message .= "<strong>$columnName:</strong> ";
            foreach ($error as $i => $msg) {
                if (is_array($msg)) {
                    $this->_parseValidationErrors($msg, $message);
                } else {
                    $message .= str_replace("This field", "", $msg . " ");
                    isset($error[$i + 1]) ? $message .= " and " : $message;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and controller code goes like this.

```
if (!$this->YourModel->saveAll($modelObject)) {
                $errors = $this->YourModel->validationErrors;
                $message = '';
                $this->parseValidationErrors($errors, $message);
                $response = array('status' => 'error', 'message' => $message);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$response['errors']['User'] = $this->User->validationErrors;
```