# CakePHP: How to handle field errors on ajax forms?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

CakePHP has a wonderful Error Validation mechanism -> all errors are automatically passed to view and are shown next to each field. Perfect.

The problem comes when you have to use Ajax. Is there a way to automate all of those things?

There is already [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413988/how-can-i-convert-validation-error-field-names-to-input-names-in-cakephp), that kind of shows how to loope over errors and pass them to JS. However I don't see any further steps. How do you put the errors next to the appropriate fields (if possible) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this approach: every input field has `id` set to `ModelFieldname` like `UserUsername`. I used something like in the link you provided, to pass error messages with names of fields to js. And in js, I used ids of fields to insert error messages something like this:

```
$(form+name).before('some styled span with error message');
```

where form is for example `#User` and `name` is the name of field with error eg. `username` (of course I had it set to upper case first).

There is probably better ways to do it, but that's what I use and it serves me well so far.

Comment: This is not very reusable it seems. Is there no other helper, or plugin or something that takes care of it?

Comment: Not that I know of, I would like to see that too.